# One-letter difference or difference of one letter?

Tags: expressions

Is there any difference in meaning between the statements below?

> Friend and fiend have a one-letter difference.

And

> Friend and fiend have a difference of one letter.

Is one of them the noun form of 'differing by one letter' or 'one letter apart'? Or are their meanings determined by context?

My assumptions is that one of them refers to difference in number and the other refers to the difference in the letter used.

Please offer your interpretation.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What difference would it make? When might you ever need to use either of your alternatives rather than the normal *Friend and fiend **differ by one letter**?*

Comment: I guess when I want to say something like 'Even the difference of one letter can greatly affect the meaning of the construction'. Or something of the sort.

Answer (score 2):

"A one letter difference" and "a difference of one letter" have the **same** meaning: that by adding, subtracting, or substituting one letter (no more, no less), the one becomes the other.